# how to use the matrix result of a pca to train a model?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

Hello I would like to reduce the dimension of my train matrix to then use a support vectorial machine, my code looks as follows:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
```

First I tried performin the pca:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=100)
#pca.fit(train_matrix)
train_matrix = np.concatenate([cities,state_matrix,work_type,company_matrix,seg,ag,rep], axis=1)
```

Then I assigned it to a variable to then train my model as follows:

```
train_matrix = pca.fit_transform(train_matrix)


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    pca, labels_list, test_size=0.1, random_state=47)
```

However I am not sure what is wrong I got, so I would like to recieve support to overcome this situation:

```
state shape:  (282521, 572)
work type shape:  (282521, 164)
train matrix shape (5000, 100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_model.py", line 61, in <module>
    pca, labels_list, test_size=0.1, random_state=47)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 2039, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 206, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 177, in check_consistent_length
    lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 177, in <listcomp>
    lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 126, in _num_samples
    " a valid collection." % x)
TypeError: Singleton array array(PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=100, random_state=None,
  svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False), dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending `pca` to the `train_test_split`. Check the arguments [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split)
Send the transformed data (`train_matrix`) into it.

Correct code should be:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    train_matrix, labels_list, test_size=0.1, random_state=47)
```

Comment: thanks a lot I finally overcome this situation, this was very helpful